# Avconv - Generate portrait image from portrait video

Tags: image, video, portrait, avconv

I am trying to generate an image from a video file using **`avconv`** function. Everything works fine except of the portrait video files. The generated image is in landscape or let's say it is turn to -90°.

```
avconv.exe -i video.MOV -r 01 -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:01 -f image2 preview-image.jpg
```

Is there any solution to generate a vertical/portrait image?

I tried to check the video information to figure out if there is a difference between portrait videos and landscape videos, but the dimensions are always as landscape on both video types.

```
avconv.exe -i video.MOV

avconv version 10.6, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar  9 2015 02:40:51 with gcc 4.8.3 (Gentoo 4.8.3 p1.1, pie-0.5.9)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2016-10-17 16:25:37
  Duration: 00:00:13.69, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4671 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 63 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-10-17 16:25:37
    Stream #0.1(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720, 4620 kb/s, 30 fps, 600 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-10-17 16:25:37
At least one output file must be specified
```

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Libav devs haven't changed anything significant from ffmpeg, you should run

```
avconv.exe -i video.MOV -vf transpose=cclock -ss 00:00:05 preview-image.jpg
```

---

Recent versions of ffmpeg will autorotate the video, based on metadata.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for. 
Just needed to change `cclock` to `clock`. Cheers!

Comment: Actually this works well for portrait videos. But in case if I don't know what type(portrait or landscape) the video is this will transform the landscape preview-image too.
Can I detect if the video is landscape or portrait ?

Comment: Recent versions of ffmpeg will display that info. Don't know about avconv.

Comment: Actually recent versions of ffmpeg will autorotate the video, based on metadata.

Comment: Works perfectly with `ffmpeg` and I would take it but I am restricted to use `avconv` for now. (FFMpeg is deprecated on our linux distribution: Ubuntyu 16.04)

Comment: I could use `avconv` with `mediainfo` (getting the needed video file information like: rotation for portrait videos). But at the end I went for `ffmpeg` cause it will avoid to run multiple commands. @Mulvya If you don't mind to create a separate answer as you precedent comment, I would accepte it.